# Problems with the namespace autoloading in composer

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, composer-php

This is a more cosmetical question...

I'm using composer.phar in an existing project to autoload my classes.

This is an example snippet of `composer.json` for my project named **Acme**:

```
{
    "autoload": {
         "psr-0": {
            "Acme\\Mail": "modules/mail/src/",
         }
    }
}
```

and a par of my file structure is like:

```
app.php
composer.phar
vendor/
modules/
    mail/
        src/
            Acme/
                Mail.php (contains Acme\Mail\Mail.php)
```

I have to stick to the folder "modules/mail" in my case and can't rename them.

**Basically this works**, but I have to create an additional folder `Acme` below `src` which is a little bit ugly.

How must the autoloading be defined, if I want to leave out the highest namespace part `Acme` in my mail folder so it looks like this:

```
app.php
composer.phar
vendor/
modules/
    mail/
        src/
            Mail.php (contains Acme\Mail\Mail.php)
```

and I still can use it like that in a php file:

```
use Acme\Mail;
$mail = new Mail();
```

Or isn't that possible?

Comment: You should read the PSR-0 standard document https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PSR4 is going to allow that to be possible. See: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/psr-4-autoloader/psr-4-autoloader.md and http://www.sitepoint.com/battle-autoloaders-psr-0-vs-psr-4/

Comment: Cool, thanks! So it's good to see, I was not the only person with that problem. ;)

Comment: It's now merged to official Composer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classmap generation if you do not want to follow PSR-0 standard (which, you really should re-consider doing). See the reference at http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload